# Can this be more Swift3-like?

Tags: swift

What I want to do is populate an Array (sequence) by appending in the elements of another Array (availableExercises), one by one. I want to do it one by one because the sequence has to hold a given number of items. The available exercises list is in nature finite, and I want to use its elements as many times as I want, as opposed to a multiple number of the available list total.

The current code included does exactly that and works. It is possible to just paste that in a Playground to see it at work.

**My question is:** Is there a better Swift3 way to achieve the same result? Although the code works, I'd like to not need the variable i. Swift3 allows for structured code like closures and I'm failing to see how I could use them better. It seems to me there would be a better structure for this which is just out of reach at the moment.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
let repTime = 20 //seconds
let restTime = 10 //seconds
let woDuration = 3 //minutes
let totalWOTime = woDuration * 60
let sessionTime = repTime + restTime

let totalSessions = totalWOTime / sessionTime

let availableExercises = ["push up","deep squat","burpee","HHSA plank"]


var sequence = [String]()
var i = 0
while sequence.count < totalSessions {

    if i < availableExercises.count {
        sequence.append(availableExercises[i])
        i += 1
    }
    else { i = 0 }
}

sequence
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can condense your logic by using [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641748-map) and the [remainder operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID63) `%`:

```
let sequence = (0..<totalSessions).map {
    availableExercises[$0 % availableExercises.count]
}
```

`map(_:)` will iterate from `0` up to (but not including) `totalSessions`, and for each index, the corresponding element in `availableExercises` will be used in the result, with the remainder operator allowing you to 'wrap around' once you reach the end of `availableExercises`.

This also has the advantage of preallocating the resultant array (which `map(_:)` will do for you), preventing it from being needlessly re-allocated upon appending.

Comment: Thx a lot! this is exactly what I was thinking about. a functional programming style structure :) I've been having a lot of trouble thinking this way... I'm pretty new to closures though.

Answer (score 2):

You can overcome from `i` using modulo of `sequence.count % availableExercises.count` like this way.

```
var sequence = [String]()
while(sequence.count < totalSessions) {
    let currentIndex = sequence.count % availableExercises.count
    sequence.append(availableExercises[currentIndex])
}
print(sequence)
//["push up", "deep squat", "burpee", "HHSA plank", "push up", "deep squat"]
```

Comment: using the % operator is something I always forget about :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, Nirav's solution is probably the best, but I can't help offering this solution, particularly because it demonstrates (pseudo-)infinite lazy sequences in Swift:

```
Array(
    repeatElement(availableExercises, count: .max)
        .joined()
        .prefix(totalSessions))
```

If you just want to iterate over this, you of course don't need the `Array()`, you can leave the whole thing lazy. Wrapping it up in `Array()` just forces it to evaluate immediately ("strictly") and avoids the crazy `BidirectionalSlice<FlattenBidirectionalCollection<Repeated<Array<String>>>>` type.

Comment: Woah, this is nice.